# Android Abstract class inheritance when access field got an nullpointerexception

Tags: android, inheritance, nullpointerexception, abstract-class

I want to design this moduls via abstract and inheritance prencible. But when access abstract class(**AbsModul**) field in inheritance class (Sms, Settings etc.) I have an nullpointerexception.

But when I was access abstract class(**AbsModul**) field in static method(**getModulMechanism()**)

How I can solve this problem?

***AbsModul.java***

```
public abstract class AbsModul {

    public  Activity
            activity;

    public  static AbsModul
            modulMechanism;

    public  Category
            category;
    public  Search
            search;
    public  Sms
            sms;
    public  Settings
            settings;

    public Category getCategory()   {return this.category;}
    public Settings getSettings()   {return this.settings;}
    public Search   getSearch()     {return this.search;}
    public Activity getActivity()   {return this.activity;}
    public void setActivity(Activity activity){this.activity = activity;}

    public static AbsModul getModulMechanism(){return AbsModul.modulMechanism;}

}
```

***ModulMechanism.java***

```
public class ModulMechanism extends AbsModul {

    public void setUp(Activity activity){
        setActivity(activity);

        super.modulMekanizmasi = this;
        super.sms       = new Sms();
        super.settings  = new Settings();
        super.search    = new Search();
        super.category  = new Category();
    };

}
```

***MainActivity.java***

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ...
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

        new ModulMechanism().setUp(this);
    }
    ...
}
```

**Null pointer problem;**

```
public class Category extends AbsModul{

    public  static String tag = null;
    ...
    public Category() {
        //I debug here
        //All AbsModul field null
        //So getActivity() reference null
        tag = getActivity().getString(R.string.categoryTAG); //Exception here > NullPointerException
    }
    ...
}


public class Sms extends AbsModul{

    Settings settings;

    ...
    public Sms() {
        //I debug here
        //All AbsModul field null
        //So getSettings() reference null
        settings = getSettings(); //Exceptions here > NullPointerException
    }
    ...
}
```

***But when access via static method work normally***

```
public Settings accessSettings(){

    //When access via AbsModul.getModulMechanism() work normally and no exception..
    return AbsModul.getModulMechanism().getSettings();
}
```

Comment: AbsModul.activity is null because it hasn't been initialised yet. You should change your Category constructor to pass in Activity as a parameter (or define a constructor in AbsModul).

Comment: i cant add constroctur have more parameter and more class extend this.. another solutions please?